# How would I handle game actions through a REST API?

Tags: php, api, rest

I have a PHP-based game that currently works in your typical request/response fashion, generating and outputting pages. I wish to completely separate the presentation and game logic, so I am porting to be API-based (using [Phalcon](http://phalconphp.com/en/)). This will also allow me to make a mobile app that can interact with the same code base.

I'm new to the whole REST API thing so I am trying to follow the guidelines set forth in [RESTful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260). It is my understanding that the API should work as follows:

```
POST to /v1/users adds a new user.
GET to /v1/users returns a list of existing users... and so on.
```

However, the client that is consuming my API (via AJAX most likely) should only issue higher-level commands. For example, I don't want a savvy user making an API call that modifies their experience. Instead, data modification would be the side effect of a game action that takes place based on player input.

For example, the client may say "hey, attack this monster", at which point the server will verify that the player has enough energy, carry out the attack, add the gold and experience to the player, and return the result to the client. These actions are very transactional, with multiple conditions needing to be true and multiple results needing to occur in order for the action to be considered successful.

I picture this functioning somewhere along the lines of:

```
/v1/attack/player - with the id of the player being a post variable.
/v1/work - with the amount of time being worked as a post variable.
```

However, this seems like it would fall under an RPC type of architecture, as defined in the book, which I understand as not the same.

- How do I handle this scenario?
- Am I correct in thinking a REST API is appropriate for this? It would seem the nature of me needing to call remote procedures is fundamentally against what I'm reading REST is.
- Assuming I am approaching this with the wrong mindset - is there some other architecture better suited or should I simply continue with the way I mentioned seeing it work?

Any advice on whether I'm headed in the right direction and what I can do better would be very beneficial to me.

Thank you.

Comment: A REST service has a limitation on the verbs - GET, PUT and so on. It seems that you need more verbs and consequently REST would not be appropriate for your application.

Comment: I understand what you mean. My thought was I could utilize the verb that makes the most sense. Some items in my game, such as high scores, would fit with the GET verb naturally. Other things, such as attacking a player, are what don't seem to fit - as that action would be creating and updating various records simultaneously but could still be accomplished by using POST or PUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would send a `POST /attack` and describe the parameters in the body. You could create links for every opponent. So this might work with simple games, but the server won't be able to push data to your browser, unless you use polling.

For realtime games an event based approach with websockets is much better...

Comment: Your suggestion of using POST /attack was what I had in mind. I wasn't sure if that was a good practice to do or not. Also, my game is not real time. The normal request/response setup is perfectly okay for this. Any updates to the client would only occur as the result of a request.

Comment: Then REST is enough for you. I suggest you to read the relevant part of the [Fielding dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) if you haven't do it yet. There are some constraints how a REST API should look like. For example you should add (probably application specific) link relations to your link and check that instead of the URL structure, etc... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Could you please clarify what you mean by application specific link relations and checking them instead of the URL structure? Thanks again.

Comment: According to the [uniform interface constraint](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) / HATEOAS subsection, you have to send back hyperlinks from your REST API to your REST clients. The REST clients follow these hyperlinks in order to achieve their goals (in your case attack the opponent). To process a hyperlink the client should check its semantics instead of the structure of the URL. The semantics is described by the link relation and probably of a vendor specific MIME type.

Comment: There are a lot of already existing [link relations](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), but you can always add your own relations. About vendor specific MIME types you can find more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Vendor_tree) and [here](http://daveyshafik.com/archives/35507-mimetypes-and-apis.html).

Comment: You can use another approach to describe semantics by sending an RDF format, for example [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/), with a REST vocab, like [hydra](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/). To use this you have to be familiar with RDF, at least currently (because there are no tutorials to learn them without RDF).

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. Thanks for all the links and information! I will surely read them all. I appreciate the time you've taken to point me in the right direction.